# How to display default image if no filename exists in Laravel database

Tags: laravel

I want to display an image for each entry in a list of posts. The name of the images are unique file names. They are all saved in a database (MySQL) table. There is more than one image for each post. The code works right. Except, when there is a post without an image filename. This is a possible scenario but i can't get the code to work. In the event there's no existing filename for a post, i want to display a default filename. 
Here's my code:

Images logic:

```
   /**
     * Get a vehicle's top or main image data from the image table
     */
     public function topImage($id)
    {
        $image = Vehiclefulldataimage::where('vehiclefulldatas_id', $id)
              ->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->first();

        return $image;
    }
```

Here's the blade view, Posts:

```
    @if (count($posts) > 0)
        @foreach($posts as $post)
            <?php $imageFilename = (new \App\Models\Logic\Images)->topImage($post->id); ?>
            <!--Item-->
            <li>
                <div class="preview">
                    @if ($imageFilename = 0)
                    <img src="{{ asset('images') . '/' . 'defaultImage.jpg' }}" alt="No photo">
                    @else
                    <img src="{{ asset('images') . '/' . $imageFilename->disk_image_filename }}" alt="{{ ucfirst($imageFilename->caption) . ' | ' . $post->title }}">
                    @endif
                </div>
                <div class="desc">
                    <h3>{{ str_limit($post->title, 100, '...') }}</h3>
                </div>       
            </li>
            <!--/Item-->
        @endforeach
    @endif
```

This is the error message i get:
"Trying to get property of Non Object"

Comment: try this 
`$image = Vehiclefulldataimage::where('vehiclefulldatas_id', $id)->first();
if(!$image){
$image = 'path/to/your/default/image'
}
`

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:
You are using an assignment operator instead of comparison operator

```
    //@if (count($posts) > 0)
@if (!$posts->isEmpty())
        @foreach($posts as $post)
            <?php $imageFilename = (new \App\Models\Logic\Images)->topImage($post->id); ?>
            <!--Item-->
            <li>
                <div class="preview">
                //@if ($imageFilename = 0) this is an assignment operator not comparison operator
                    @if ($imageFilename->isEmpty())
                    <img src="{{ asset('images') . '/' . 'defaultImage.jpg' }}" alt="No photo">
                    @else
                    <img src="{{ asset('images') . '/' . $imageFilename->disk_image_filename }}" alt="{{ ucfirst($imageFilename->caption) . ' | ' . $post->title }}">
                    @endif
                </div>
                <div class="desc">
                    <h3>{{ str_limit($post->title, 100, '...') }}</h3>
                </div>       
            </li>
            <!--/Item-->
        @endforeach
    @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your if statement....what you're doing there is an assignment and not a condition test...you can include a column..with a string pointing to the path of your default image..and set it to default...then load it...as default image

Answer (score 0):

All of the answers above fix your problem. However, I recommend you to fix this problem by using Laravel features, Mutators.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators

Laravel mutators allow you to format or modify your Model attribute.

Just in your Vehiclefulldataimage model write the code below:

```
public function getImageAttribute($value) 
{
     //can write more logic here.
     return $value ?: 'path/to/your/default/image';
}
```

Then you don't care more if condition blade template. If your image is empty the mutator returns the default image. So, everywhere when your retrieve Vehiclefulldataimage instance the mutator works properly

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.
After looking at all the answers, i did a simple alteration to my code. I altered:
`@if ($imageFilename = 0)`

to:
`@if ($imageFilename == null)`

Thus, my code now looks:

```
@if (count($posts) > 0)
        @foreach($posts as $post)
            <?php $imageFilename = (new \App\Models\Logic\Images)->topImage($post->id); ?>
            <!--Item-->
            <li>
                <div class="preview">
                    @if ($imageFilename == null)
                    <img src="{{ asset('images') . '/' . 'defaultImage.jpg' }}" alt="No photo">
                    @else
                    <img src="{{ asset('images') . '/' . $imageFilename->disk_image_filename }}" alt="{{ ucfirst($imageFilename->caption) . ' | ' . $post->title }}">
                    @endif
                </div>
                <div class="desc">
                    <h3>{{ str_limit($post->title, 100, '...') }}</h3>
                </div>       
            </li>
            <!--/Item-->
        @endforeach
    @endif
```